# How to configure SharePoint forms based authentication

Tags: sharepoint, forms-authentication

Can someone please tell me how to do the following in SharePoint (WSS 3.0):

Have a user log in (user name and password) on a page and then if correct display the home page of a WSS 3.0 site?

I think it's called forms based authentication.

Answer (score 3):

[Here's a video](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/In+the+Office/Anonymous-Access-and-Forms-Authentication-with-WSS-30/) about using Forms Auth. with WSS3 and [here are some samples](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288259.aspx).  Basically, you use the login.aspx page in _layouts to collect credentials and cache them.  You have to modify web.config to use the membership provider.  More on that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457529.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the best article on [FBA](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/HowToConfigPublishingSiteWithDualAuthProvidersAndAnonAccess.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself a lot of time and checkout http://sharepointsolutions.com/SharePoint-Add-ons/Products/Pages/ExtranetCollaborationManager.aspx

I have done it several ways but this has made life easier when configuring environments.

Answer (score 0):

As a special case of Forms Based AuthN, in case you don't have to own the DB containing your users, you can rely on Live ID to authenticate users to your site. Haven't tried [this](http://blog.solanite.com/keith/WLA/default.aspx), but may help you.

Answer (score -1):

I just believe some JavaScript is enough to do that.Maybe I am Wrong!

Comment: ？？ I said"Maybe I am wrong!" Reputation is nothing to me, but if I lose it just because my answer is not the right one. I just：-（